# Get Data According to Group by date field

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table

[image]

Which have field type which means 1 is for income and 2 is for expense

Now requirement is for example in table there is two transaction made on `2-10-2018` so i want data as following

```
Expected Output

id   created_date   total_amount
1       1-10-18     10
2       2-10-18     20(It calculates all only income transaction made on 2nd date)
3       3-10-18     10
and so on...
```

it will return an new field which contains only incom transaction made on perticulur day

What i had try is

```
 SELECT * FROM `transaction`WHERE type = 1 ORDER BY created_date ASC
 UNION
 SELECT()


//But it wont work
SELECT created_date,amount,status FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(amount) AS totalTrans FROM transaction WHERE created_date = created_date
    ) x
 transaction
```

You can Also See Schema HERE **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6983b9**

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: SQL Fiddle link is not working.

Comment: Works fine In my compute

Comment: @TarangP you want to count the total number of expense transactions on a date, or get the SUM of total expense done on a particular date ?

Comment: No.Your Answer is perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) the total number of expense transactions using conditional function [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), on a group of `created_date`.
- Similarly, you can [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) the amount of expense done using [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), on a `created_date`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  `created_date`, 
  SUM(IF (`type` = 2, `amount`, 0)) AS total_expense_amount, 
  COUNT(IF (`type` = 2, `id`, NULL)) AS expense_count  
FROM 
  `transaction` 
GROUP BY `created_date` 
ORDER BY `created_date` ASC
```

Comment: i just have to ask only because i left the practise of sql. well thanks @Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: Respected @Madhur Bhaiya You can see my comment On `Gordon Linoff` And Answer. it would be appreciated.

Comment: @TarangP Since both are transactions, you can store them in one table. As in future, you will need to do lot of computations using both income and expense. So, you can avoid a join later on, when tables become big.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT t.created_date, SUM(amount) as total_amount
FROM transaction t
WHERE type = 2
GROUP BY t.created_date
ORDER BY created_date ASC ;
```

Comment: Yes I want where to define whether it is income or expense

Comment: Respected @Gordon Linoff I just want to ask you as you are expert in sql. is it good idea to develop only one table which have all transaction. means 1 for income and 2 for expense. is this correct Or Second idea is to develop two table having incom or expense seperat. which idea was good.